# How can I access a character's alternate font glyph to use in UILabel or UIButton text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to use alternate font glyphs in the text of a UILabel. For example, SF Mono has a "0" with no slash. I can see the alternate glyphs in Photoshop, if I use one as a text object and copy/paste it as a character to Xcode, it doesn't paste as the alternate, it pastes as the usual slashed version.

[image]

Comment: What does "in Xcode" mean? It's easy to use the slashed or unslashed zero in your _app's interface_. But that is not "in Xcode", so please explain what _you_ want to do. Thanks.

Comment: In the text of a UILabel, etc. When I paste the unslashed zero into a String, it pastes the slashed zero.

Comment: You won't see a variant when you paste text into a label _in Xcode_ (e.g. in a storyboard). You have to set the variant in code when the app runs.

Comment: Basically I would say Xcode (the code/interface editing program) is not set up for the kind of thing you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't know how to set the alt glyph in code. If I have `label.text = "\u{0030}"`, how do I further specify which glyph to use?

Comment: Well if you are going to set `label.text` you aren't going to be specifying _any_ glyphs. The label has a font and that's that.

Comment: I want to use SF Mono in some UILabels, and I want to use the zero with no slash. Can it not be done?

Comment: Yes, it can, but you have to set the font's stylistic variant in code. I've demonstrated in an answer. Sorry it's such a pain, but as I say, Xcode itself is not set up for this. It's not really a typography application, the way, say, TextEdit is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to achieve this using mere copy and paste in Xcode. You're going to have to drop down to the level of core text and do it in code.

In this example, I'm using SFMono to display two zeroes, but one zero has the slash and the other doesn't:

```
let f = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
let desc = f.fontDescriptor
let mas = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "00", attributes: [.font:f])
let d = [
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kStylisticAlternativesType,
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier: kStylisticAltThreeOnSelector
]
let desc2 = desc.addingAttributes([.featureSettings:[d]])
let f2 = UIFont(descriptor: desc2, size: 0)
mas.addAttributes([.font:f2], range: NSRange(location: 1, length: 1))
self.label.attributedText = mas
```

And here's the resulting label:

[image]